# Transparent background iframe only working in Firefox and not Chrome or Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

I'm trying to get a transparent background on an iframe, but I only am able to get it working on firefox. I have tried all the different ways of getting it to work, but this is the css that I'm using now on the page that is in the iframe:

```
html, body {
    background: linear-gradient(top, blue, transparent);
}
```

| This is the result in Firefox(and the desired result): | And this is what I get in chrome of safari: |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

The iframe that I add using JavaScript:

```
<iframe class='repoImg' allowtransparency='true' frameborder='0' src='objectpreview.html?objecturl="+ element +"' title='3D model of "+ element +"'>
```

Is there a way to get the desired result across all browsers?

Comment: Does your `object.html` file have the background set as transparent for the `body` element in CSS or the style attribute?

Comment: @SierraKomodo I use `objectpreview.html` in the iframe, and the background is set to the `html` and `body` element as I show in the css in the post, and the css is in file `objectpreview.css` only used in `objectpreview.html`.

Answer (score 0):

iframes default to transparent

```css
html, body {
    background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="data:text/html,<DOCTYPE html><h1>This is an iframe</h1>"></iframe>
```

If the iframe is setting a background color on it's own then it will use whatever color it chose. But if it does not set a background color then it's transparent and shows through to the parent's page.

Since you're getting a different result, something in your iframe is making that white color.